# How can I get trigger to copy data from a picklist field to copy over to two custom fields?

Tags: apex, trigger

I am trying to get data from a picklist field (Source) to automatically copy over to two custom picklist fields (Primary Source/Secondary Source) unless there is already data in the Primary Source at which point it would just copy to the Secondary Source field. I wrote an apex trigger which is working correctly to copy the data to the Secondary Source field, but I can't seem to get it to copy over to the Primary Source field unless I put "!=null" which negates the point of the trigger. Any idea why this isn't working or a better way of getting this to work?

```
trigger UpdateSources on Lead (before insert, before update) {
    for(Lead editedLead: trigger.new){
        if (Lead.Primary_Source__c == null) {
            editedLead.Primary_Source__c = editedLead.Source__c;
            editedLead.Secondary_Source__c = editedLead.Source__c;
        } else {
            editedLead.Secondary_Source__c = editedLead.Source__c;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value `Lead.Primary_Source__c` is a token representing a field (and so is never null). See e.g. [Using Field Tokens](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_dynamic_field_tokens.htm).

You probably intend `editedLead.Primary_Source__c` which is the value of the field on the object instance you are looping over and may or may not be null.

Comment: That fixed it. Thank you! Should have caught that but thank you so much. Seriously helped.

Comment: @HannahB. Sometimes it just needs a second pair of eyes.